# Concatenate binary files in windows (Without command line)

Tags: windows, gui, binary-files, concatenation

I'm trying to prepare a process for copying the video files off of a recorded DVD (we made the recording, and it's not encrypted). The method of copying the VTS_*.VOB file works when the recording is short and there is only one, but if there are multiple I need to concatenate them.

On my *nix box, I would just `cat VTS_1.VOB VTS_2.VOB > ~/Video.VOB`, but the computer now runs windows, and the person who does this in the future will not have command line experience.

Is there any GUI application/solution to concatenate these files? Or would the best bet be to write a custom application (If I do, it would be in Java)?

Another note, we are currently running windows XP, but it could be running Windows 7 or 8 in a few months.

Comment: sounds like it might be a bit dodgy.. even mp3 files are a bit funny when combined, like the length doesn't show up right even though it plays. maybe wav is ok combined, that'd be audio of course. dunno about Vob

Comment: @barlop VOB files are formatted such that simply concatenating the files will combine the video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File joiner: https://www.igorware.com/file-joiner

[image: File joiner]

- File Joiner 64bit (x64) and 32bit (x86) versions available
- freeware
- portable (no installation needed, no need for .net or runtime library's of any kind)
- ...